# How to limit WAR classload in Wildfly to the WEB-INF folder only (not have visibility on EAR/lib folder)?

Tags: wildfly, classloader

I'm trying to add a self-contained WAR to an existing EAR.  Given that my new WAR has some much more recent libraries, I want to ensure at all costs that there are no conflicts with any existing libraries that are present within my EAR.

At the moment, my EAR is structured as:

```
EAR:
 - webapp1.war
 - ejb.jar
 - lib/lib1.jar
      /lib2.jar
      /lib3.jar
 - webapp2.war  <-- the new self-contained war
```

To limit any potential conflicts, I will package my `webapp2.war` as a completely self-contained WAR, with all its dependencies in the WEB-INF/lib folder.  But to be even more certain, I want to limit the classloader for the webapp2 to its WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib folder.

I found [this classloading reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) for Wildfly, but the only thing I found in the document is the `exclude-subsystems` tag:

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="" />
    </exclusions>
  </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But I read this to mean that I would need to create a new subsystem entry for every lib (ie: module) in the ear/lib folder.  Which is not very manageable.  Additionally, I'm not even 100% clear of what the module name should be?

- deployment.ear.ear.lib1.jar?
- ear.ear.lib2.jar?
- ear.ear.lib3.jar?

Is there any way to simply tell the classloader to ignore all modules/libs in the EAR/lib folder?  Is there a maven plugin I can use to otherwise generate this automatically for me?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just deploy the WAR separately.

If you really need to do this then simply including the WAR in the EAR should *just work*.

Aside from APIs provided by the Java EE/SE specifications, everything else in a WAR file's WEB-INF/lib (and classes) directory will always be seen before the class loader looks into the EAR and elsewhere. This is a specification requirement.

Things will get messy if you forget a library and a class is picked up from the EAR though. That class may return an object that references one of your duplicate libs resulting in strange class access problems.